# Only one axis rotation

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to rotate object like below using fixed pipeline OpenGL? If yes - how can I do this? The 0,0 point is in the corner of 3d object, parallel point must be higher or lower than the 0,0 point by a known amount. I know object width, too.

[rotation http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1686/beztytuurax.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1686/beztytuurax.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a rotation, but a shearing operation, and as such an affine transformation - so it is representable by the usual 4x4 transformation matrices used by the fixed-function pipeline. You can achieve such effects by combinations of rotations, translations and non-uniform scales, or you can directly specify a shearing matrix and use it via glLoadMatrix/glMultMatrix.

In your drawing, you just use a shearing along one axis, so the x coordinates stay the same. This can be done in general with a matrix like:

```
1 0 0 0
v 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

which leaves x, z and w as it is and transforms y to y+v*x, so v controls the amount of the shearing.

Comment: I had to put my v in row 0, column 2, I am using shearing after rotations and before translation - it works, but gives strange results: [v=0](http://screenshooter.net/1003588/ltkuote), [v=0.1f](http://screenshooter.net/1003588/tbjuamh), [v=1f](http://screenshooter.net/1003588/wivritw) - what can be the cause and how to fix this?

Comment: @Mac70: well, you never specified a coordinate system, i just assumed the standard mathematical definition on the 2D drawing you supplied to illustrate my point, so the actual aces might be different. Also, there might be the well-know row-major vs. colum-major oder issue. Your result with v=1 looks very strange indeed. But without seeing some real code, nobody can tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

That transformation is not a rotation, it's called shear. It's also a linear transformation, so you can implement it with `glMultMatrix`. You're going to have to figure out which matrix you need to multiply with though. Google shear.